# Place text made with Geometry Generator outside feature

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator

I wished to know if there's a way to make the Font Marker don't cross or be inside the the feature, as shown in the images bellow.

The text is not a label, but made in Geometry Generator with "Point/Multipoint" as Geometry Type. I imagine there's a solution with an expression in the Rotation or Offset properties, but I'm not well familiar in writing them yet.

This is the text settings:

In simbology, add a symbol layers with Geometry Generator as type. This is the expression I use:  `nodes_to_points( $geometry)`. Geometry type: Point/Multipoint.

Then in Symbol layer type I put "Font Maker". And in property Character(s) I use this expression:

```
'P' || to_string ( with_variable('new_position',
  with_variable('n_to_p', nodes_to_points(force_rhr($geometry)),
    with_variable('array_coord_y', array_foreach(
        generate_series(1, num_points(@n_to_p)), y(point_n(@n_to_p, @element))
      ),
      array_find(@array_coord_y, array_first(
          array_sort(
            @array_coord_y, ascending:=false
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  if (
    @geometry_part_num <= @new_position,
    num_points($geometry) - 1 + @geometry_part_num - @new_position,
    @geometry_part_num - (@new_position)
  )
)-1)
```

This is how it is right now:
[image]

This is how I wanted it to be, the text outside the feature:
[image]

Comment: Please add the whole label settings in text form, thank you.

Comment: I wrote all the settings that I use to create the text. Hope it helps, thanks!!

Comment: I suspect you may need to generate the points as a virtual layer (with labels) and then use the polygon's labelling settings (labels>placement>obstacles>settings>minimise placing labels over the feature's interior) to ensure those labels are always outside the polygon. I can help with generating the points in SQL but the label text column I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the complexity of your polygons, you could get their boundaries, offset them using a miter join type (2) and then convert to points for pseudo-labelling.

```
nodes_to_points( 
 offset_curve( 
   boundary($geometry),
   0.05, 
   join:=2))
```

[image]

Comment: It would work if only it didn't duplicate some vertices. I don't know why it happens, but in duplicating the vertices it won't be a true representation of the polygon I'm working. I don't think there's a function that offsets the polygon preserving number of vertices, is there? I searched for it after seeing your answer but couldn't find anything. Thank you.